# Tensorflow: adding Feedforward to LSTM

Tags: tensorflow, lstm, feed-forward

How can I add an additional feedforward layer before a standard LSTM network, using Tensorflow?

Answer (score 0):

```
n_timesteps = 15
n_dim = 5

model = models.Sequential()
model.add(layers.TimeDistributed(layers.Dense(10, activation='relu'), input_shape=(n_timesteps, n_dim)))
model.add(layers.LSTM(25))
model.add(layers.Dense(2, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam')
```